# How to get the equivalent of combinig [contains] and [in] operators in the same query?

Tags: directus

So I have a field that's a multi-choice on the Directus back end so when the JSON comes out of the API it's a one-dimensional array, like so:

```js
"field_name": [
                "",
                "option 6",
                "option 11",
                ""
            ]
```

(btw I have no idea why all these fields produce those blank values, but that's a matter for another day)

I am trying to make an interface on the front end where you can select one or more of these values and the result will come back if ANY of them are found for that record. Think of it like a tag list, if the item has just one of the values it should be returned.

I can use the [contains] operator to find if it has one of the values I'm looking for, but I can only pass a single value, whereas I need all that have either optionX OR optionY OR optionZ. I would basically need a combination of [contains] and [in] to achieve what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to achieve this?

I've also tried setting the [logical] operator to OR, but then that screws up the other filters that need to be included as AND (or I'm doing something wrong). Not to mention the query gets completely unruly.

Help?

Comment: The "blank" items are likely due to the value being wrapped with the delimiter. You can disable this by turning off the `wrapWithDelimiter` interface option.